# Return an object from a function in CoffeeScript

Tags: object, three.js, coffeescript

I have a piece of code I am writing that should animate a 3D scene. I do this having the 3D scene structured neatly in code using classes and functions. This works on itself as a text out-putting thing.

Logically it needs to not spit out just text. The library Threejs should interact with what I build.

I want to do something like this for example:

```js
class Tile extends SuperSpace
  height: 2
  sideLength: 10
class Plain extends Tile
  constructor: ( { @color = 'lightgreen', @height = @height, @heightPlacement = 2 } = {} ) ->
    console.log """
                  New plain:
                    color: '#{@color}'
                    sideLength: #{@sideLength}
                    height: #{@height}
                    heightPlacement: #{@heightPlacement}
                """
  mesh: ->
    geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry 10/10, 2/10, 10/10
    material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial { color: 0x22ff22 }
    cube = new THREE.Mesh geometry, material
    return cube
```

And call it in the scene simply like this:

```js
scene.add plain.mesh
```

Which is nothing more and less than a altered existing example from the docs. `plain.mesh` should be the returned `cube`

Somehow the object doesn't get trough. I either get `undefined` or I get my entire function back in the console:

```js
function () {
      var cube, geometry, material;
      geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10 / 10, 2 / 10, 10 / 10);
      material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0x22ff22
      });
      cube …
```

Hardly satisfying. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a function reference: `plain.mesh`. This is a function call: `plain.mesh()`. The parentheses are required when there aren't any arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
class Tile extends SuperSpace
  height: 2
  sideLength: 10
class Plain extends Tile
  constructor: ( { @color = 'lightgreen', @height = @height, @heightPlacement = 2 } = {} ) ->
    console.log """
                  New plain:
                    color: '#{@color}'
                    sideLength: #{@sideLength}
                    height: #{@height}
                    heightPlacement: #{@heightPlacement}
                """
  mesh: ->
    geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry 10/10, 2/10, 10/10
    material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial { color: 0x22ff22 }
    cube = new THREE.Mesh geometry, material
    return cube

plain = new Plain()
console.log plain.mesh()
```